# How to get all Post from specific Category using category name?

Tags: php, wordpress

** I want to get all Post by categories**

**Here Is my Code but not data not showing by categories**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'    =>  'project',
    'category'     => 'recent-projects',
    'numberposts'  => -1,
    'order'        => 'ASC'
); 
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: are you wanting all posts in all categories? if so i think you just remove the category key

Comment: Provide more code, we can't guess what get_posts() does and what is the error?

Comment: manqlele, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

Comment: When you say all categories, do you mean you want a list of all posts, regardless of categories? or you want a list of all posts, sorted by categories somehow?

Comment: You asked about this already, not even a full day ago - [How do i get all post by categories in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65682388/how-do-i-get-all-post-by-categories-in-wordpress) Please do not create such duplicates in cases, where the discussion of the problem could have easily continued under the already existing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
**I Used This code And this is working for me**

$args = array(
    'category_name' => 'category slug name', //Category Slug name
    'posts_per_page' => 3  // Number Of Post,Use -1 For All Post related This category
); 
$posts = get_posts($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your posts are not on published, they will not be shown.
You should add 'post_status' to your $args array like this

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' =>  'project',
    'category' => 'recent-projects',
    'numberposts'    => -1,
    'order'=> 'ASC',
    'post_status' => array('any'),
); $postslist = get_posts( $args );
```